# Write a dataframe as an excel sheet in r

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to write different dataframes as an individual excel sheet.
Here is an example:

```
Node<-write_xlsx(Node,paste0(My_path,Model1,'My_Excel_file_2020.xlsx'),sheetName = "Nodes",col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

It gives me an error:

```
Error in write_xlsx(Node,paste0(My_path,Model1,'My_Excel_file_2020.xlsx'),  : 
unused arguments (sheetName = "Nodes", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

I have gone through this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/writexl/writexl.pdf but no success.

I tried to install and use alternative `writexl` package which give me this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
 .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
  Fehler: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

Could anyone help me in this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many of the packages to work with Excel have a Java dependency. This can be annoying - and is a problem you are having now. I prefer to use the package `openxlsx` because it has a bunch of features and does not have this dependency.

Comment: The `writexl` package does not have java as a dependency. Try restarting R.

Comment: Good to know. I just assumed so based on the error saying `rJava` cannot be loaded.

Comment: It's possible one of the output functions (e.g. `write_xlsx`) is masked by the `xlsx` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It could be a typo.

First, make sure that libraries are correctly loaded by executing these lines:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("readxl")
library("xlsx")
```

The first error you get, makes me think that you want to actually use `write.xlsx()` function instead of `write_xlsx()`.

Try to execute this code:

```
Node <- write.xlsx(Node, paste0(My_path, Model1, 'My_Excel_file_2020.xlsx'), sheetName = "Nodes", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @ Louis, Thanks. Actually I cant use library `library("xlsx")` because of `rJava` dependancy otherwise I would have used `write.xlsx`. I have used `write.xlsx` before and worked fine but meanwhile something went wrong and it started giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `writexl` package, you can set the sheet names for the individual dataframes like so:

```
writexl::write_xlsx(
  list(
    sheetname1 = df1,
    sheetname2 = df2
  ),
  "excel_file_name.xlsx"
)
```

EDIT: To modify an existing workbook, you can use `openxlsx`.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook("path/to/existing/workbook.xlsx")

addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "newSheetName")
writeDataTable(
  wb,
  sheet = "newSheetName",
  x = df,
  startCol = 1,
  startRow = 1
)

saveWorkbook(wb, "nameOfWorkbook.xlsx")
```

`openxlsx` has a lot of additional functions for customizing the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks @Fleur De Lys, I modified code line like `Node<-writexl::write_xlsx(list(Nodes=Node),paste0(My_Path,Model1,'My_Excel_file_2020.xls)` but it replaces whole excel file with only `Nodes` sheet and I don't understand how to use `append = TRUE`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. Is node a single dataframe? A list of dataframes?

Comment: no it's a single dataframe named `Node`  and already there are 4 more sheets in `My_Excel_file_2020.xlsx`. I am just adding another sheet `Nodes` keeping rest of excel sheet as it is.

Comment: Ah, then you'd need a package with more features; `writexl` is unable to modify existing workbooks (see [here](https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/2)).
I prefer `openxlsx`, and have updated my answer to include a solution using it.